# How to keep dcu files in per project folder (e.g.: .\$(Platform)\$(Config)\$(ProjectFilename)?

Tags: delphi

I have lot of Delphi projects in a project group.   I can set `Unit output directory` to `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)` and all dcu files  will keep in the directory according to `platform` and `config` value.

In my build environment, I would like to set the `Unit output directory` to something like  `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)\$(ProjectFilename)` so all DCU files shall keep in it's own directory identified by current project file.

The Build Events in `Project | Options` has `$(ProjectFilename)` macro but I can't use it in `Unit output directory`.

I want to set `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)\$(ProjectFilename)` to all projects' `Unit output directory` and it will keep all DCU files in unique project directory.

Comment: The `$(Platform)` and `$(Config)` variables (as well as all others identified by `$(varname)`) are set by the IDE on startup, so they don't exist when the IDE isn't running. If you want the equivalent, you'll need to set your own environmental vars.

Comment: When coding, I switch from a project to another project.  It is tedious to change the ProjectFileName environment variable when I switch project.

Comment: That it's tedious doesn't change the fact that the environmental variables created by the IDE don't exist when the IDE isn't running. :-)

Comment: If there is a variable that return a unique value everytime we reference it will solve my problem too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this answer coincidentally.  I pick one project and (ms)build with verbosity of `diagnostic`.  By studying the output of `msbuild`, I simply pick a variable: `MSBuildProjectName` and specify in my `optset` file shared by 300 projects:

```
<DCC_DcuOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)\$(MSBuildProjectName)</DCC_DcuOutput>
```

And I try build all projects in IDE.  Amazingly, `Delphi` create folders for each project built and keep the DCU files in the folders respectively.

Comment: That's quite slick and I did wonder whether or not there would be a variable like that. I still wonder about your 300 projects which seems odd. But nevermind my concerns! You absolutely need to be automating generation of all you dproj and dpr files. Then you can apply policy changes centrally and robustly.

Comment: I construct dproj, dpk and dpr files manually from time to time as my project grows.  I use `optset` files shared among projects to specify various build options.

Comment: You really need to automate this. Then everything will be easier and safer. Time to learn a language like Python and write some tools.

Comment: My projects are mostly runtime packages (`.bpl`).  Each project has different `.pas`, `.rc` files and required packages.  I don't see the point to automate my projects.

Comment: You keep the variations in distinct template or specification files. If you can't recognise the fragility of making the same change manually to 300 distinct projects then so be it.

Comment: @Chau:  If the projects all use different units then I don't understand why you are so concerned with isolating the DCU output for each project.  What problem are you trying to solve ?  If it's simply about manageable file organisation on disk then I think you have asked the wrong question.  You should be asking how to best organise projects with the specific characteristics and relationships in your specific case, with sufficient detail that useful answers can be given.

Comment: @Deltics: Delphi or it's `MSBuild` script build projects in a project group one by one regardless of what CPU you are using.  I have successfully write some `MSBuild` scripts to filter and organize the `DProj` files to `BuildInParallel` in multi core environment.  However, I have few `WeakPackage` units that used in several project.  Build these projects in parallel will crash due to WeakPackage `DCU` file creation.  That's the reason I want to keep `DCU` files in per project folder to avoid the crashing.

Comment: And the information previously hidden but crucial to the understanding of the problem just keeps on coming.... Since you *created* the problem by editing MSBuild directly, perhaps that is also where you should be looking for the solution, rather than in the IDE which does not actively support what it is that you are doing ?  Just a thought.

Comment: @Chau:  I missed that these comments were on your own answer, not on the original question.  I see now that the solution you found was indeed by further extending your customisations within the MSBuild environment.  Congrats.  :)

Comment: There's a list of other helpful MSBuild variables you can use at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The *Build Events* pre-processors supports a range of macros, some of which are equivalent to some environment variables.

The *DCU Output* folder setting supports only **environment variables** and not these macros.

**Possible Alternative Approach**

To get a *per-project* DCU folder you can take a different approach, making **dcu** a subfolder of the current project, e.g.:

```
Unit Output Directory: .\dcu
```

(or perhaps just "dcu", but I prefer to include the ".\" if only to make it clear that the relative setting is intentional)

This achieves the objective of keeping the DCU's for each project separate from each other, but means you no longer have all DCU's in a separate location outside of the project folder.

You can of course still use the $(platform) and $(config) variables in this relative path, if this is important to you:

```
Unit Output Directory: .\dcu\$(platform)\$(config)
```

Whether this is an acceptable compromise only you can say in your situation.

Often the intention of keeping DCU's in a location other than the project folder is to:

- keep the project folder "clean"
- avoid having to maintain a long list of "ignore" entries for each dcu file in VCS (SubVersion/Git etc)

Keeping DCU's in a project subfolder achieves the first of these, and the second issue is much simplified by being able to add just the DCU subfolder to the VCS ignore list, to ignore any file in that DCU folder.

Comment: My projects (.dproj and .dpk) files are stored in same folder.  The per- project approach you propose doesn't work either.

Comment: Easy way out then is to put each project in its own sub folder

Comment: I have 300 dproj files keep in same directory.  It is hard to restructure the dproj files to make one project per folder.

Comment: Each project in a sub folder and output path to `..\$(platform)\$(config)` and dcu output path to `.\$(platform)\$(config)`

Comment: 300 projects in the same folder?  That's a key piece of information that wasn't in the original question.  It seems to me that you need to re-state the question in terms of the problem you are trying to solve with these projects, rather than how to address a specific IDE behaviour.  I suspect the only answer to the problem as now clarified is a per-project specific DCU Output setting and to use a user environment variable so that you can change your DCU 'root' without having to change each project setting, e.g. :  $(DCU)\ProjectName  (where $(DCU) is a variable you define in the IDE).